# Collection view cells show same images when I pass next images

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to show images in a collection view from an array of URLs.
Inside `cellForItemAt` I am checking each URL in an array for whether it is an image or a video by using a loop.
Then if it is an image I set it to the cell's image view. If it's a video then I fetch the thumbnail from it and then again set the cell's image view.

The problem is on setting the cell's image view. All the cells image's change to the last image passed.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = imageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as? photoCell
    
    for mediaPaths in imgarr {
        do {
            let url = mediaPaths
         
            let typeID = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]).typeIdentifier
         
            let supertypes = UTType(typeID!)?.supertypes
            if supertypes!.contains(.image) {
                
                //print("Image file")
                cell?.cellImageVIew.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgarr[indexPath.row].path())
                
            } else if supertypes!.contains(.movie) {
                print("Video file")
                
                cell?.cellImageVIew.image = getThumbnailFrom(path: mediaPaths)
                
            } else {
                print("Something else!")
            }
         
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return cell!
}
```

- Imgarr : is the array which has directory URLs of all the images and videos.
- under cellForItemAt function, using for loop to check each URL for media type and then pass it to image view.

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense. The `cellForItemAt` method gets called to fetch the image for a single cell at a specific `IndexPath`.

In that method you loop through your array `imgarr` of image descriptions, load every one in turn, and install it into your cell's image view. No matter which `IndexPath` you are being passed, you load ALL the images in your array, and the last one will be left in the cell's image view once the loop is complete.

Don't loop through all the images. Use the `indexPath` parameter that's passed to you to figure out which image you should load, and load just that one into your cell's image view. (Collection views can display a one-dimensional list of cells, a 2-dimensional grid of cells, or some other abritrary grouping of cells. If you are displaying a 2-dimensional list of cells, you might be able to simply use the `indexPath.row` to index into your array of image descriptors.)

Comment: Note that loading images from disk into memory (and decompressing them) is somewhat slow. If you have a modest number of cells, you might write your code to load all the images in your array into memory on a background thread. That would give you smoother scrolling of your collection view at the cost of a larger memory footprint. Even if you load images one at a time as needed in your cellForItemAt  method, you should probably store them into your array in memory so you don’t re-load them every time the user scrolls away from a cell and back to that cell.

Comment: I think NSCache would be better that loading all of them up front

Comment: NSCache is a good suggestion. I forgot about that class.